# How to create xorg.config file?

Tags: 14.04, xorg

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a VM and my tutorial requires a `xorg.config` file, which I can't `find`. I was looking it up and it said it's not default any more, but I can't seem to understand any tutorials on how to create it. Could someone explain it step by step please?

EDIT: To clarify, the `stop gdm` bit is especially confusing, as `gdm stop` doesn't do anything and `service gdm stop` turns it into a black screen where I need to restart the system.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Just create a `xorg.conf` file with the settings you need. There is no "default" file any more...

Comment: We don't know what you follow, post a link to clarify. You most certainly do not need to stop anything just to create a file.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal window:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Copy/paste whatever you need there, then ctrl-o to save, ctrl-x to exit.

Ubuntu 14.04 has lightdm instead of gdm, and to stop lightdm, run

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Comment: Aren't there supposed to be other things in it, and won't it get weird if it can't find certain variables?

Comment: xorg.conf is not there by default, so it would be very weird indeed, if you do find something in the file that doesn't exist.